# Spring MVC Returns HTTP 400 when sending more JSON than expected

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

Currently I'm working on an ajax application that sends HTTP PUT requests via JSON to Spring 3.2 MVC controllers.

Everything is working fine except for the case where your JSON data does not match the expected @RequestBody class exactly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{companyId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void update(@PathVariable long companyId, @Valid @RequestBody AdminCompanyForm adminCompanyForm) {
    adminCompanyService.updateCompany(companyId, adminCompanyForm);
}
```

For example, let's say we are sending a JSON object containing `id` and `name` fields, but the @RequestBody object only contains a single field called `name`.

In this case, Spring MVC will send an HTTP 400 response code (i.e. Bad Request) without any other form of error message. The solution is to change our Javascript code so that the JSON data only contains a `name` field. When doing that, everything works perfectly.

My question is this: How can I tell Spring not to send an HTTP 400 error when too much JSON is sent to an HTTP PUT action on one of my controllers? When an extra `id` field is sent via JSON, I want Spring to simply ignore it. I don't want it to be too strict. Having to manually delete JSON fields to match what the server expects exactly is honestly extremely time consuming, and I want to make my life easier.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Accept the request body as a string and deserialize with in the controller method and have your exceptions catched.

Comment: I have about 100+ controller methods that need to accept put requests. Is there no other way to make spring do the right thing without having to add manual code to take back control away from spring? That sounds like a bummer :( I am also using @Valid as well, which means I'll also have to manually check validation too. I am not sure that this solution will make my life easier in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring the object mapper,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

You may write a simple test case with this object mapper. It will ignore unrecongized fields.

Now we need to configure spring mvc to use this custom object mapper. You may write a factory bean returnning ObjectMapper:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    </bean>        
</mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

 <bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="yourCustomObjectMapper" />
```

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks! I had it not fail for serializing, but I forgot all about this feature.